# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 on Modification Page -Opencart Version 3.0.3.3

Tags: opencart-3

Getting HTTP ERROR 500 on Modification Page Opencart 3.0.3.3 when refreshing modification in admin
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: error 500 does not say anything. you should to check error log on your server. But this error can cause some module (extension). How to solve if you do not know where is the problem? Solution: You can connect via FTP to you server and delete all files and directories from storage/modifications folder. just leave index.html file. After that you can login to admin and remove your modules/extension one by one till the refreshing of the modification do not cause an error.

Comment: Ive seen this error alot in Opencart 3 when refreshing Modifications. I normally just refresh the page and the error is gone. All of my extensions work just fine, so I'm thinking it may just be an Opencart 3 bug. It could be that an OCMOD is calling something wrong? Does refreshing the page clear the issue?